Calculating a line and sphere intersection rollback
I'm trying to calculate a rollback distance of a sphere colliding with an oriented box to move the sphere back on a given vector by that distance so it's touching the box on a single collision point. The box can only be rotated on Z axis and the sphere is moving in 2D on X and Z axis.
It's not that difficult to calculate it when the collision point ends up on one of the sides as the collision vector is always perpendicular to the plane. But I can't figure out how to calculate the distance when the collision point is on an edge. I was thinking I could work with the edge as if it was a line and try to calculate the distance needed to move the sphere so there is a single point of intersection.
Let's say there's a sphere with radius 0.5 and center at (0.5, 0.5, 0) intersecting a line starting at (0, 0, 0) with direction to (0.5, 1, 0) and I need to move the sphere in direction of (0.2, 0, -1). The resulting distance should be approximately 0.41 placing the sphere at (0.58, 0.5, -0.4), but I'm not sure how to calculate it.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

No comments or answers suggests you didn't explain your question well.
